# LWUIT: How to assign Label to the Textfield

Tags: java-me, lwuit

i want to assign a label to the `TextField`. I am using the following code

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
Label label = new Label("Pick a unique username");
textField.setLabelForComponent(label);
textField.setConstraint(TextField.ANY);
form.addComponent(textField);
form.show();
```

the above code is not showing the associated label for the `TextField`. How can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excerpt of the `Component` from the LWUIT javadoc @ [**link**](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Component.html)

```
public void setLabelForComponent(Label componentLabel)

Allows us to indicate the label associated with this component thus providing 
visual feedback related for this component e.g. starting the ticker when the 
component receives focus. 

Parameters:    
componentLabel - a label associated with this component
```

Hence your are just associating a `Label` with this `Component` and now actual binding them together as perceived / visually single group.

.

I would recommend you use `ComponentGroup` with `TextField` and `Label` added to it, also you can style them as a group. Check [**this**](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/iodocs/com/sun/lwuit/ComponentGroup.html) link for more information on `ComponentGroup`

**PS:** `ComponentGroup` is available from **LWUIT 1.5**.

Comment: WC, consider accepting this answer to help future readers of this post.